# Most efficient way of matching file names with Ruby regex

Tags: ruby, regex, file, dir

The method `Dir.glob` is used for achieving file names that match a certain pattern, but its argument has a Unix-like syntax (e.g., using `*`, `**` as wild cards in a particular way, etc.). Instead, I want to use Ruby (Onigmo) regex for the matching pattern to do the same thing (using its wildcards, quantifiers, anchors, escaped characters, etc). What is the best way to do this?

One simple way that comes to mind is to use `Dir.glob` to get the list of all existing files in all directories, and filtering them using the regex, but that does not look efficient. Or, is it? Is there a better way?

Comment: looks efficient to me.

Comment: How about unix command `grep` inside [*backtick*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-60) ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit How do you do that? Are you sure you got the question correctly?

Comment: why do you worry about performance? encapsulte the functionality, and improve it later if it's a bottleneck.

Comment: @sawa `grep` command understand all kind of regex, and it will let you write the regex as you need. Write it down and then run it `%x(grep pattern)`. Do `man grep` and read the manual. Nicely they wrote it.

Comment: @sawa, Maybe he meant `find`, not `grep`: Some `find` variant like GNU find accept `-regex` option: `find /path/to/dir -regex #{pattern}` (couldn't surround backtick)

Comment: @ArupRakshit, `grep` normally match file content, not a filename.

Comment: @falsetru Sorry, Yes I meant so.. :-)

Comment: @sawa I was seeing `find` and by mistake told you to see `grep`. It is `find`. Do `man find`, to see the doc.

Comment: + I don't recommend to use backtick. It will wait until the command to be terminated and return whole output as a single string. If you really need all the output at once, you'd better to handle filename by filename. (by readling output line by line). See [`Open3`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html)

Comment: Anyway, as I wrote clearly, I want to use Ruby regex, not a different variant of regex. Also, I do not want it to be OS dependent.

Comment: @sawa Then have a look at [this](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/126625#564661)

Comment: Arup, perhaps @phrogz would like to post that as an answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yeah sure... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the [Find module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html) in Ruby's standard library.

```
require 'find'
Find.find(path).grep(/regex/)
```

The find method returns every path that exists within the path you provide as an argument recursively, pretty much like what you mentioned with Dir.glob. You can then use the built-in grep method to filter the results with a regex.

This may not be the most efficient method though, since Dir.glob is written in C while the Find module is written in Ruby. I did a test on my home directory and it took Find a little longer to get the result than Dir.glob, but you can also use the Find module's prune method in order to not descend into particular folders, which could help make things more efficient using Find.